# escape characters in velocity for aws api gateway

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, escaping, aws-api-gateway, velocity

I'm currrently returning some values from an API Gateway method (attached to a Lambda) with the following code:

```
[
#foreach($element in $input.path('$.elements'))
  {
    "field1": "$element.field1",
    ...
    "name" : "$esc.java($element.name)",
    ...
  }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end    
]
```

Since name can have characheters lika " and \ that break JSON, I need to escpae them, so folloewing the manual, I'm using:

```
"name" : "$esc.java($element.name)",
```

but I get the result

```
"name" : "",
```

Any idea why? Or any option, please? I can't find anything around.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS does not provide the `EscapeTool $esc` in its [predefined context variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html).

I don't see in its `$util` anything interesting for you. But you must remember that you have access to all the methods of the `String` object, so you can do:

```
$element.name.replace('\', '\\').replace('"', '\"')
```

Comment: Hi guys, I used the suggestion from Claude and it worked as expected. I did encounter a strange issue however: the escaped characters displayed correctly when I viewed the result in AWS Console, but it appears un-escaped in POSTMAN or curl or anywhere else. After much debugging, I finally figured out that it was because I had a big portion of the mapping template set up as a param in the Cloudformation template to avoid defining it twice, but the API apparently didn't like that. Just wanted to point that out in case anyone else encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1):

A new function is added for that purpose. [`$util.escapeJavaScript()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#util-template-reference)

Comment: This will escape "too much" as it escapes all JavaScript String characters. In JSON only a small subset is needed like control characters \n, \t, etc.